# IntelliJ can't find javax.servlet.*

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, gradle

I am currently facing a strange issue where IntelliJ can't process my code. Something like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    ...
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
    ...
}
```

where `authenticationFilter` returns an instance of `GenericFilterBean`. This code compiles using Gradle just fine, but IntelliJ complains that my `AuthenticationFilter` and `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class` don't match the required parameters `javax.servlet.Filter` and `Class<? extends javax.servlet.Filter>`.

Upon further inspection, it seems that the class file that defines `GenericFilterBean` doesn't see the `javax.servlet` package so in my file, it doesn't know what it is.

Another interesting thing is that `spring-ws-core` has a dependency on `spring-web:4.0.9.RELEASE` and my code depends on `spring-web:4.3.2.RELEASE`, and when I look at the classes inside the 4.3.2 references, it can see `javax.servlet`, i.e. `GenericFilterBean` on 4.0.9 breaks, but on 4.3.2 works.

Also, if I do

```
if (authenticationFilter() instanceof Filter);
if (new UsernameAuthenticationFilter() instanceof Filter);
```

IntelliJ says I could replace both with `!= null`.

When I run `gradlew dependencies`, I can see dependencies like `org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.9.RELEASE -> 4.3.2.RELEASE`, but IntelliJ displays both in the Gradle Projects view and in the project references.

My project has a multi-project gradle build and the 4.0.9 dependencies are on the subprojects.

### What I tried

- refreshing the gradle dependencies (through IntelliJ)
- invalidating IntelliJ caches
- cleaning the project (`gradlew clean`)
- reopening IntelliJ
- reinstalling IntelliJ
- restarting my computer

### Temporary solution

As suggested by @Jens, I added `compile('javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0')` to `allprojects` and now IntelliJ can parse it correcly, although it would be better not to have "hacky" dependencies on the build file.

Comment: Not sure this will help, but did you try invalidating caches?

Comment: Yeah, did that too, will add it to the question

Comment: Which class in javax.servlet package you try to Import?

Comment: @Jens in my code, I only reference `Filter`, but one of the broken dependencies references (`GenericFilterBean`) references `Filter, `FilterConfig`, `ServletContext` and `ServletException`, all of which it can't find

Comment: Have you treied to add the dependency `javax.servlet-api`?

Comment: @Jens I had tried it, but I hadn't tried to add it to the subprojects (forgot to mention that it had those). Now it appears to be working, although I'm not sure this is actually a good solution, since as I said, Gradle builds it normally, it's just IntelliJ that can't parse my code, and I think my build file shouldn't be dependent on which IDE I'm currently using...

Comment: @rtomchinsky You are right. Buildfile shoulkd be undependend from the IDE. But i am wondering that the gradle build works.